# Is it possible to retrieve a password stored in OpenVPN?

Tags: password, openvpn

I reinstalled my Mac and forgot to backup my username and password to my VPN provider.

The good thing is I also have VPN installed on my android where it works fine and logs in automatically. So the password exists on one of my devices. The problem is: How do I recover it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.

- If your Android phone is rooted, just use a [root explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root%20explorer&c=apps) and inspect the app's data under /data/data/[com.your.vpn.app's.name]
- Use "adb backup" ([Win/Linux app here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=36499906)) and extract it with [ADBExtractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/p://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/)
- Use [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) (an adb backup frontend), it produces the same backup type that's extractable with ADBExtractor like above.

You can determine your apps internal name by finding it on Google Play and looking at the the URL: E.g., [OpenVPN for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn) has de.blinkt.openvpn as internal name

Comment: Helium is just a frontend to ADB. I can confirm it uses exactly the same `.ab` format, as I've been able to restore backups created by Helium using command-line `adb restore helium-backup.ab`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Haven't tested it since its been renamed from Carbon to Helium and couldn't remeber the format.

Comment: No root needed for *Helium* or `adb backup` usually. Where "usually" refers to the fact that with root *Helium* offers a few additional features.

Comment: @facas: use method 2 or 3. dont root, it'll wipe your data. For security reasons, and with good cause.

Comment: I have now gotten my com.apnames.android.ab and run: java -jar abe.jar unpack com.appname.android.ab result.tar. the output looks fine but it does not appear to be a valid tar achive sin I cant untar it. //facas